# Using langchain's Faiss, the similarity computation results are low

Tags: python, embedding, langchain

When utilizing langchain's Faiss vector library and the GTE embedding model, I've encountered an issue:
even though my query sentence is present in the vector library file, the similarity score obtained through `thesimilarity_search_with_score()` is only 0.9.
Here is the code snippet I'm using for similarity search:

```
model_name = "BAAI/bge-large-zh-v1.5"
model_kwargs = {'device': 'cuda'}
encode_kwargs = {'normalize_embeddings': True}  # set True to compute cosine similarity

model = HuggingFaceBgeEmbeddings(
    model_name=model_name,
    model_kwargs=model_kwargs,
    encode_kwargs=encode_kwargs,
    cache_folder="../model/",
)

db = FAISS.load_local('../dataset/bge_faiss_db', embeddings=model, index_name='index')

query = '无纸化发送失败?'
res = db.similarity_search_with_score(query, k=3)
```

My Results:

```
[(Document(page_content='无纸化发送失败?'), 0.9069208), (Document(page_content='凭证打包失败?'), 0.57983273), (Document(page_content='edi发送不了?'), 0.5719995)]
```

I would like to seek assistance in understanding the potential reasons for this discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use other model for embedding. Since the method to calculate distance is always same.

Here I use L2 distance which 0 is the best score:

```
from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS


embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

loader = TextLoader("./text.txt", encoding="utf-8")
documents = loader.load()

db = FAISS.from_documents(docs, embeddings)

query = '无纸化发送失败?'
res = db.similarity_search_with_score(query, k=3)

Here I use L2 distance, which 0 is the best score.
# output
[(Document(page_content='无纸化发送失败?', metadata={'source': './text.txt'}), 0.0)]

query2 = '纸化发送失败?'
res2 = db.similarity_search_with_score(query2, k=3)
res2

# output
[(Document(page_content='无纸化发送失败?', metadata={'source': './text.txt'}),
  0.08518691)]
```